# How to create custom background for UITableView section?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a custom background for my tableview section. The look I'm going for is this: [image: The section itself has rounded corners, but each cell doesn't.]

How do I customize the tableview section background/layer please, rather than just the individual cells?

Edit: Just to clarify - I'm talking about the white background under 'Latest Transactions'. So the top of the section is rounded (as is bottom) but all the rows are rectangular.

Comment: Are you talking about that rounded rectangular white color background? You can just set background to individual cells. First one and last cell of the section should have a rounded image. other cells should have a rectangle image.

Comment: What section background in the image are you talking about?

Comment: Just to clarify - I'm talking about the white background under 'Latest Transactions'. So the top of the section is rounded (as is bottom) but all the rows are rectangular.

Comment: What about forcing your UITableview to use Inset Grouped Style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `UITableViewCell` subclass and add a `UIView` with white color. Add left & right padding for the view to the cell. Add `UILabel` and other `UI` elements to this newly added view instead of adding in `cell` or its `contentView`. Set `cell` background color as `UIColor.groupTableViewBackground`

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    let bgView = UIView()
    let label = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {

        backgroundColor = .groupTableViewBackground

        bgView.backgroundColor = .white
        bgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(bgView)

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bgView.addSubview(label)

        bgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        bgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        bgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        bgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

        label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Use this cell class in your `tableView`. And set your view controller background color and `tableView` background color as `UIColor.groupTableViewBackground`

In `cellForRowAt` check if the cell is first or last cell of the section. If it is the first cell of the section, apply corner radius to top left, top right corners. If the cell is the last cell of the section, apply corner radius to bottom left, bottom right corners. If the cell is in the middle remove corner radius.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.backgroundColor = .groupTableViewBackground
        tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
        tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 10)
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Section \(section) Title"
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as? CustomCell
            ?? CustomCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
        if indexPath.row == 0 {//first cell of this section
            cell.bgView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
            cell.bgView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            cell.bgView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
        } else if indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)-1 {//last cell of this section
            cell.bgView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
            cell.bgView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            cell.bgView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        } else {
            cell.bgView.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        }
        cell.label.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `func headerView(forSection section: Int) -> UITableViewHeaderFooterView?` 
[headerView(forSection:) - UITableView | Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614965-headerview)

Answer (score 0):

Use UITableViewDelegate method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        <#code#>
    }
```

This will help you to set the view of each section header programatically.

Answer (score 0):

To create a section header in `tableView`, use `UITableViewDelegate's` `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` and `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)` methods.

```
func getHeaderText(for section: Int) -> String? {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return "Latest Transactions"
    default:
        return "Other Transactions"
    }
    //Add other cases for different sections 
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 70.0)))
    headerView.backgroundColor = .clear
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: headerView.bounds.width - 40, height: headerView.bounds.height))
    label.text = self.getHeaderText(for: section)
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .semibold)
    headerView.addSubview(label)
    return headerView
    //Customize the headerView as per your requirement
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 70.0
}
```

In the above code, you can configure the `header label` in `getHeaderText(for:)` for each `section`.

Also, I've created the `headerView` programatically. You can use a `.xib` for creating a custom `headerView` as well. That's completely your choice.

You can customize the `headerView` as per your requirements either programatically or in the interface.